# How to close cursors opened by java class in PL/SQL database?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jpa-2.0, cursors

I've a case where I call a java source from PL/SQL package and in java source, I insert data to my database table. By this insert operation, a cursor is left open every time I make a call.

I can't make changes to this java source and hence can't close the resultset there.

So I want to write some PL/SQL code in my package to close the cursor after every call to java source and insertion of data.

How can I do so? I don't want to increase my ***maximum open cursor*** limit.

Comment: Why isn't the Java code cleaning up after itself, and why can't you fix that?

Comment: The Java code is managed and modified by other team and they have recently implemented JPA, earlier it was Toplink. I guess these changes are restricting it from cleaning itself.

Comment: If the routine you're calling returns a cursor you could write another Java function that calls the existing Java function and then closes the cursor when finished. If the cursor which is being left open is not available outside the routine you're calling then "the other team" needs to fix this resource leak. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using preparestatement to execute the sql, then you can create a different object to hold off the data and then can close the statement to close the cursor.

don't close the statement before transferring the data to a different object otherwise you will get a  Closed statement error.